# macOS enable reduce transparency option except for dock?

Tags: big-sur, dock, color

My goal is to enable reduce transparency option except for `Dock`, which leads the gray line around the dock.

Or at least if reduce transparency option is enable I want to remove the gray outline line on the dock, where you can see on the `After` image.

OS: `macOS Big Sur Version 11.4`

---

Setup:

- SystemPreferences => Accessibility under the Display tab and checkmark "Reduce Transparency"
  ￼

[image]

---

Before:

[image]

After, Here gray line around the dock is annoying and I want to remove it, if possible.

[image]

- Appearance: `Dark`
  -Desktop: `Dark` Theme is selected.

---

Same edge coloring issue could be observed in between the top menu bar and a windows (where app's border edge color remains light in the dark-mode):

[image]

---

Related Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68012022/2402577

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the only way is to create a Desktop wallpaper image that has a single color strip where the Dock sits, so that any transparent effects are negligible.

Comment: I am using dynamic desktop wallpapers that are dark. Desktop wallpaper image does  not have any impact on the dock's background color

Comment: Yes, but a single color will reduce all transparency effects. Apple does not make customizing the UI easy, if at all possible.

Comment: @benwiggy Alper wants everything except the dock to have reduced transparency. Your solution is making only the dock and nothing else transparent, meaning it's the opposite of what alper wants. Your solution works, but only if reduced transparency is off. And it isn't too hard to customize mac UI. I use this free app called tinker tool to modify the Mac UI, but unfortunately, it cant do what alper is asking.